# Gaming server Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a batch file that I can leave running, if "Unturned.exe" is not running to `start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.lnk"` and then idle and scan and wait for it to shutdown again. like in a loop.

This is what I am using now, but there is no communication between this and the server for people to know that it is about to restart. I only run 1 server now.

```
@echo off
cls
color B


:loop

echo ===========================================================
echo ===========================================================
echo ======== UNTURNED SERVER RESTART SCRIPT By FATBOI =========
echo ===========================================================
echo ===========================================================

@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
echo ===========================================================
echo Killing all servers for restart...
echo ===========================================================

@timeout /T 1 /nobreak >NUL
taskkill /f /im Unturned.exe
echo ===========================================================
echo All servers have been killed
echo ===========================================================

echo ===========================================================
echo Servers starting...
echo ===========================================================
start "" /b "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.lnk"
@timeout /T 30 /nobreak >NUL


cls

echo ===========================================================
echo ===========================================================
echo ===== UNTURNED SERVER RESTART SCRIPT By JoeCooper2015 =====
echo ===========================================================
echo ==================Server Restart Time======================
echo ===========================================================
time /T
echo ===========================================================
echo ===========================================================

REM Every 4 hours kill and start servers. note 1H = 3600 seconds
REM use timeout then goto loop
@timeout /T 3600 /nobreak

goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:MyLabel
start "" /w Mygame.exe
Goto MyLabel
```

Pretty simple.

This is how to do it in VBS

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```